# Iterate over a []rune | string passed in generics

Tags: go, generics

I am working with generics with this constrained rule:

```
type LineParser[T []rune | string] struct {
}
```

And I have this generic method of that struct:

```
func (it *LineParser[T]) Parser(line T)
```

Inside of that method I want to iterate the line but I am getting this error:

> invalid operation: cannot slice line (variable of type T constrained by []rune|string): T has no core type

any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Convert the `line` value to a `[]rune` value before iterating. This way, every instance of the method will iterate over the same type.

```golang
type LineParser[T []rune | string] struct {}

func (it *LineParser[T]) Parser(line T) {
    for _, r := range []rune(line) {
        // do something with the next rune
        _ = r
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try tomorrow morning and tell you if it works

Comment: Cant convert to a []rune i need iterate both a []rune or string

Comment: @FernandoGonzález `range` over `string` and `[]rune(string)` will produce exactly the same values of `r`. Is there another problem?

Comment: I know but sometime my strings has special chars that gave me errors with rune when it happens I run the same func but this time with string and everything its ok. This just happen when the string contains special symbols

Comment: @FernandoGonzález Go `string`s and surrounding tools are well equipped to handle special characters, if you use utf-8 encoding (the default almost everywhere). If you show the specific operations you are trying to do, then maybe I can see what mistake you're making in the code.

Comment: cant show you, but the error is in this part:
`number, err = strconv.Atoi(string(line[2:4]))

  if err != nil {
   return err
  }`
When it has special chars the rune gave err but string not.

Comment: maybe i need to make the text in utf-8 before send to the func

Comment: Go language and standard library assume utf-8 encoding for strings unless otherwise specified.